# Section of a house for wiring and plumbing

Tags: выбор-слова

How is that limited-height section of a house under a floor or roof (usually reserved for wiring and plumbing) called in Russian?

EDIT:
The term in English is 'crawl space'. Google Translator rendered it as 'пространство сканирования', which I believe is wrong.

Comment: And how does it called in English? If there's a specific term  - have you tried to find its translation? In other words was there any additional research beforehand? Usually  this information helps to provide more informative answers as well.

Comment: @shabunc - does it called, it's translation

Comment: in case the conventional term isn't found i believe ***техническое пространство*** may suit

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка not sure I got what you are saying.

Comment: @shabunc just pointing out mistakes

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка ah I see, I make plenty of them

Comment: @shabunc - "And how does it called in English? If there's a specific term - have you tried to find its translation? In other words was there any additional research beforehand?" - The term is 'crawl space'. Google Translator rendered it as 'пространство сканирования', which I believe is wrong.

Comment: @brilliant can you please update you question with exactly this information?

Comment: @shabunc - Just added. Don't really see how that could be helpful, though.

Comment: here you can look up more suggestions [**crawl space**](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=crawl+space)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There're two terms

[**техническое подполье**](https://dic.academic.ru/searchall.php?SWord=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B5) and [**технический чердак**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/bse/139517/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

They obviously only suit the entire house, not a separate apartment in an apartment block.

For an apartment ***техническое пространство*** (под полом/над потолком) may fit the bill, but this is an improvised generic term for lack of a better one (to my limited knowledge).

Comment: A larger-dimensional term for larger buildings is `технический этаж`, but it's a (more or less) full storey, even if it's too small for an adult man to stand. The point is that these technical rooms might be _not_ beyond the ground or on last floor, but also in-between.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of the space under the floor, it would probably be referred to as "подпольное пространство", literally "under-the-floor space". There is also the word "подпол" which is closer to "crawl space" or "cellar", somewhere you could put jars or  vegetables for storage.

As for the space above the ceiling, I am not quite sure these were widely used in Russian architecture.

Comment: `Подпол` is technical space all right. Cellar is `погреб`.

Comment: These are pretty much interchangeable in Russian. Hence Wikitionary even lists them as synonyms.

Comment: I wonder if those dictionary writers even been to a countryside.

Answer (score 1):

I just came up with another similar term from a different view point.

## Аппаратная

It's basically an "device room", which can be anything. This is rather a room in a building and not a storey, but for that see other questions.

Things like the access door to the elevator motor or a boiler room might be labeled as such.